# Call to a member function count() on integer Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have database row called cat_id and in this row i have categories id's from 1-17

http://prntscr.com/mgrlbz

How could i show count of category no 17?

Comment: downvoted because there is no effort added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your controller

```
$data['count'] = your_table::where('cat_id',17)->count();
return view("YOUR_VIEW_PATH", $data);
```

Use it in your blade template

```
<div>{!! $count !!}</div>
```

Comment: ok, and maby you can help me with blade how to bring him in to my content?

Answer (score 0):

Using sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name where cat_id = 17
```

Or if you have query results like `$rows = data_array` then you can use php like

```
$count = count(array_filter($rows, function($item) { return $item['cat_id'] === 17; }));
```